# .map function continue running after Return

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I'm running a basic .map function and an if-else inside and I want that if it found something it returns and stops the loop but it's continuing and I don't understand why I believe the response is pretty simple.

The function :

```js
const isInFieldsTemplate = (fields, field) => {
  fieldsTemplate.map((item) => {
    if (field === item.label) {
      console.log(field + 'IIIIIIIIIII' + item.label);
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
};
```

Data Example:

```js
field: Quantity

fields:
[
  { label: 'createdBy', value: 'createdBy' },
  { label: 'Quantity', value: 'Quantity' },
  { label: 'location', value: 'location' },
]
```

So if you run this function with this data the loop will not stop at Quantity and return true it will simply continue and return false.

Comment: Map function always runs for all the values in an array, You need to use filter/find instead of map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `map` is to create a new array with a transformed version of everything in the original array.

If you aren't using the return value (the new array) from `map` then you shouldn't be using `map`.

If you want to search for the first item in an array that matches some condition: use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), not `map`.